# Caliper Issue Question

Tags: honda, brakes, civic, brake-calipers

I have a 2014 Honda Civic EX with about 65K miles on it. I have been told that for some reason our calipers aren't 'firing correctly'. Two questions, one, it seems like I only get this recommendation when I take our vehicle to the dealership to get it looked at for other issues, I saw online that calipers should last for the life of the vehicle in most cases. I am the first owner and I made sure to purchase the 100K warranty, without knowing specifics, do you think this issue should be covered? And if not, what is the typical cost associated in this type of work? How necessary is it to get this fixed, sooner rather than later?

Thanks so much for any and all help!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You'll need to read what the extended warranty states. It will specify whether or not you are covered. As Sam Basso stated, the caliper and brackets are not typical wear items, so should be covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brake pads are usually considered consumable and would not likely be replaced under warranty. Brake calipers and brackets are a different story and not "consumable" in the same way. It's up to the dealership to decide if it wants to honor the warranty on the calipers, you would have to take it in and let them check the brake system. That's if the calipers are actually at fault, which they may not be. A bigger question is WHY the calipers aren't operating correctly, and the answer is probably upstream.

Are the brakes loose? Pedal going to the floor? Uneven breaking and vibration/shaking when you brake? You could be low on or have contaminated fluid. There could be something stuck in the ABS solenoid like air or debris.

Who told you the calipers weren't working and why did they think that? If you don't notice any of the symptoms of a failing brake system, then what is wrong?

Comment: That is the weird thing, the brakes seem fine when driving. No different then when driving 2 years ago, this started initially when I brought it to the dealership to address a recall, they did their 19 point inspection or something and they let me know that when looking at the brake pads, one side of the rear brake pads were more worn then the back. And I do get the regular tire rotations and brakes done when I am supposed to. That and the bill made me take it over to Les Schwab and when i went there, they just changed the brake pads and recalibrated something and said that should do it.

Comment: But now that i am back to the dealership, they're bringing this up again?

Comment: When they bring up the uneven wear, ask them WHY is it unevenly worn or WHAT is causing the issue, also if they will cover the parts/inspection. All you can do.

Comment: Probably bad/stuck/rusty slider pin(s) on the calipers.  Simple fix.  This is because the slam-bam pad slap brake jobbers tend to overlook this important extra step - checking and regreasing the sliders, which allow the "active" piston side and the "dead" pad-only side to balance forces when pinching the rotor.